# Can I implement hashCode and equals this way for (Hash)Sets?

Tags: java, hashset

I know that if `a.equals(b)`, we must have `a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()` else we get strange results, but I'm wondering if the converse is also required.

More specifically, I have a `hashCode()` function that uses the field id to calculate the hashCode. However, my `equals()` function only uses the simple comparison `"=="` to check for equality. This may seem strange but unless more details are required, it's simply how I've implemented it.

Now the question is will this mess anything up? Specifically for HashSets, but more generally, for any (common) implementations of Set.

The way I understand it, a Set will first check the hashCode then the equals operator to see if a duplicate object exists. In this case, it should work right? If two objects are the same instance, they will produce the same hashCode as well as return true for `equals()` and thus the Set will only allow the instance to be be added once.

For two separate instances with the same id, the hashCode will be identical but then the `equals()` operator will return false and thus allow both objects to enter the Set, which is what I hope to accomplish.

Is this a beginner's mistake? Am I missing something? Will this have an unexpected results for any collection types other than Set?

---

edit:

I guess I should explain myself. I have a Hibernate object FooReference which implements both a hashCode and equals method using the id. This object is guaranteed to always have a unique id. However, before this object is persisted, I use a Foo object which has a default id of -1. So when putting it in a Set (to be saved) I know each Foo is unique (thus the basic == operator). So this Foo which extends FooReference overrides the equals method with a basic ==. For my purposes this should work... hopefully.

Comment: Why would you override `equals` such that it calls `==`, when this is what the `equals` defined in `Object` does?

Comment: Because my object extends another object in which the equals() method is more complex than the default equals().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects are allowed to have the same hashcode without being equal to each other.  In fact, it's perfectly valid (though inefficient and a bad idea) to implement `hashCode` as simply `return 0`, giving *every* instance the same hashcode.

All that's required is that if two objects are equal (as determined by the `equals` method), they have the same hashcode.

However, if your `equals` method just compares the two objects using `==` internally, no two (distinct) instances will ever be equal to each other, so there's no point defining your own `hashCode` and `equals` methods at all.  The default implementations will produce the same behavior.

Comment: Please see my updated question. I'm thinking of having an if statement such that if the id == -1 I use a simple == operator. Otherwise equals() will be based on the id as well.

Comment: So that all (distinct) instances with an ID of -1 are unequal to each other, but instances with other IDs can be equal?  Yes, you could do that.  It's not a problem for all the instances with ID -1 to have the same hashcode (though you may see poor performance adding/removing items in the `HashSet` if there are large numbers of them).